# Maze solver infinite recursion

Tags: java, recursion, maze

I am trying to implement a recursive maze solver in Java and have run into an infinite recursion issue. Here is the code, it seems to be bouncing up and down, which is what is causing the infinite recursion, but I can't figure out how to stop it.

```
Key:
1 is a wall
0 is an open space
2 is part of the solution
3 is the end
```

---

```
public class MazeSolver{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int[][] maze = {{1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
      {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1},
      {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1}};
    int r = 0;
    int c = 0;
    boolean[][] posCheck = new boolean[maze.length][maze[0].length];
    for(int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++){
      for(int col = 0; col < maze[row].length; col++){
        if(maze[row][col]==0){
          r = row;
          c = col;
        }
      }
    }
    maze[r][c] = 3;
    mazeSolver(1, 0, "", maze, posCheck);
  }

  public static boolean mazeSolver(int r, int c, String d, int[][] maze, boolean[][] posCheck){
    posCheck[r][c] = true;
    if(maze[r][c] == 3)
      return true;

    else if(maze[r][c] == 1)
      return false;

    else{
      if(c+1 < maze[0].length && !d.equals("Right") && !posCheck[r][c+1]){
        if(mazeSolver(r, c+1, "Left", maze, posCheck))
          maze[r][c] = 2;
      }
      if(r+1 < maze.length && !d.equals("Down") && !posCheck[r+1][c]){
        if(mazeSolver(r, r+1, "Up", maze, posCheck))
          maze[r][c] = 2;
      }
      if(c-1 >= 0 && !d.equals("Left") && !posCheck[r][c-1]){
        if(mazeSolver(r, c-1, "Right", maze, posCheck))
          maze[r][c] = 2;
      }
      if(r-1 >= 0 && !d.equals("Up") && !posCheck[r-1][c]){
        if(mazeSolver(r, r-1, "Down", maze, posCheck))
          maze[r][c] = 2;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  public static void print(int[][] maze){
    for(int row = 0; row<maze.length; row++){
      for(int col = 0; col<maze[row].length; col++)
        System.out.print(maze[row][col]);
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: To make your code more readable (even for yourself) use better names (what are `r`, `c` and `d`? I can guess r is row, or c is column but you see  that I am guessing which is not good).

Comment: r is row/ c is column/ d is direction it came from

Comment: If it's possible to reach the same position again in a path, you must store state as you advance and check that you haven't been here before. The easiest way is to use a `Set` of positions and check that the position you're about to advance to is not in the set.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Recursive Maze Solver problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239871/java-recursive-maze-solver-problems)

Answer (score 0):

Maze values are passed by reference, which means that your values are being changed when they are not supposed to be.

You have to remove the path after you back track.

Simplify your logic like this -

```
boolean solve(Maze maze, Position current, Position destination){
  if(maze.isSolved(current)){
    return true;
  }

  for(Position p: maze.getNeighbourCells()){
      if(maze.isWall(p)) continue;
      if(maze.isOutside(p)) continue;

      maze.markPath(p);
      if(solve(maze, p, destination)) {
        true;
      }
      maze.removePath(p);
  }

}
```