# Maze Traversal Algorithm Using Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, traversal, maze

I'm trying to traverse a maze using recursion for class.  I was provided the template and just need to input the the process of traversing the maze;  I am not allowed to alter the code in any way besides what is being plugged in after this:

```
public boolean mazeTraversal (char maze2[][], int x, int y)
```

I have been having a really hard time with this and don't know what I am missing. I am still and ultra noob when it comes to Java and programming in general.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
 // Exercise 18.20 Solution: Maze.java
//Program traverses a maze.
import java.util.Scanner;

package maze;


public class Maze {
public static void main( String args[] )
{

}
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

static final int DOWN = 0;
static final int RIGHT = 1;
static final int UP = 2;
static final int LEFT = 3;
static final int X_START = 2;
static final int Y_START = 0;
static final int move = 0;
static char maze [][] =
{ { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' },
    { '#', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
    { 'S', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#' },
    { '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
    { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', 'F' },
    { '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
    { '#', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
    { '#', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
    { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '#' },
    { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#', '#', '#', '.', '#' },
    { '#', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '#', '.', '.', '.', '#' },
    { '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#' } };
     static Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

      //method calls mazeTraversal with correct starting point and direction
      public void traverse ()
      {
      boolean result = mazeTraversal (maze, X_START, Y_START);

      if (!result)
      System.out.println ("Maze has no solution.");
      } //end method traverse
      //traverse maze recursively
      public boolean mazeTraversal (char maze2[][], int x, int y)
      {
      // TO BE COMPLETED
      //check for boundaries
      if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= maze.length || y >= maze[0].length)
      return false;
      //base case - did I reach finish?
      if(maze [x][y] == 'F')
      return true;
      //check if Valid point
      if (maze [x][y] != '.' || maze[x][y] != 'S')
      // hit a wall, not valid 
      return false;
      //must be on a path, may be the right path
      //breadcrumb
      maze [x][y] = '.';
      //up
      if (mazeTraversal (x+1,y))

      {
      maze [x][y]= '#'; 
      return true;
      }
      if (mazeTraversal (x,y+1))
      {
      maze [x][y] = '#';
      return true;
      }
      // can't go any further
      return false;
      }
      } 

      //draw maze
      public void printMaze()
      {
      // for each space in maze
      for ( int row = 0; row < maze.length; row++)
      {
      for (int column = 0; column < maze [row].length; column++)
      {
      if (maze [x][y] == '0')
      System.out.print (".");

      else
      System.out.print (" " + maze [x][y]);
      }
      System.out.println();
      }
      System.out.println();
      }
      }
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239871/java-recursive-maze-solver-problems/22242301#22242301 for some hints - looks pretty close to what you are starting with.

Comment: would you say I'm on the right track now?

Comment: First point is that your code is not formatted, and does not actually compile. If you fix that up, it is much easier for people to look at your problem and give you some help. See below for an actual answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

On any given point, you will have 4 directions to move to if you or not on the edge, with the given constraint that you cannot move diagonally or through walls.
Start with an empty 2x2 matrix, and on every step you can take near the starting point, mark a "1" because it takes one step.

Afterwards, mark a "2" to adjacent legal steps that does not already have a number.

Next, mark a "3" to all adjacent legal steps next to the 2s that already does not have a number.

Ultimately, this will end up filling the whole matrix with legal moves and the minimum amount of moves that will lead to a spot.

By only marking a number to a spot that have not already been assigned, this will avoid backtracking or stepping on a step that can has already been reached earlier. This ensures that the matrix will be filled with "best possible routes."

(See where the recursion comes in? :) )